# next previous link that read and load internal url arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create my own "previous" & "next" buttons on my portfolio that will read from a set or arrays that load static php file. I'm not againsts even doing in js, but I assume php might be easier since all my files are in php.

Looking for a simple loop to call and load the pages...

```
var pages = [
 "index.php",
 "project1.php",
 "project2.php",
 "project3.php",
 "project4.php",
];

 var Current = 0;
```

with some sort of function for prev(); and next();

```
function Prev(){
  if(Current == 0){
    Current = pages.length - 1;}
   else{
   Current--;}
}

function next(){
  if(Current == 0){
    Current = pages.length - 1;}
   else{
   Current++;}
}
```

them have my html look something like this...

```
<a href="prev();" class=“prev”>Previous </a>
<a href="next();" class=“next”>Next </a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using `AJAX` ?

Comment: You should use `<?php next(); ?>` to call functions. Your `next` and `prev` functions should return the URL, they do nothing in that link. `Current` should be `$current`.

Comment: Thanks AmmoPT. Not 100% sure what you mean though. I'm a bit new to this. How do I return the next and prev URL and have the browser act on the switch?

Comment: No to ajax @ths.

Comment: @NicholasZdravkovski that can be done with `JavaScript` or `PHP` which one you prefer, but one last point, in the `index.php` you will have next button points to `project1.php` and prev button points to `project4.php`, in the `project1.php` the next points to `project2.php` and the prev button points to `index.php`... and so on. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

One would be to add an `iframe` to your page and changing its `src` attribute to your page URL when one of the buttons is clicked. Another would be to have some container (e.g. a `div`) and then load the HTML dynamically (e.g. via `fetch` or AJAX) and insert it as the `innerHTML` of said container.

Comment: Thanks H,B, but i'd rather not use iframe. Looking to have each page have its own URL.

     www.domain.com/project1
     www.domain.com/project2
     etc